# Резиновый input на остаток строки

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы `input` занимал весь остаток строки сразу за `label`?

Comment: Изначально ответ был для [удалённого вопроса](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/651873/178988), решил запостить отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
div { white-space: nowrap; }
label, span { display: table-cell; }
label { width: 0; }
span { width: 100%; }
input { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="a">Первый input</label>
  <span><input type="text" id="a" /></span>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="b">Второй</label>
  <span><input type="text" id="b" /></span>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="c">И ещё с длинным-длинным тексом</label>
  <span><input type="text" id="c" /></span>
</div>
```

Обращаю внимание на обёртывание `input`а в `span` - без него так не получится, т. к. `table-cell` плохо сочетается с `input`ом.